# Software industry sector sizes

Tags: language-agnostic

Are there statistics or even estimates anywhere regarding the sizes of the various sectors of the software industry (e.g. desktop, systems, embedded, business, games etc.)?

Comment: A fine example of a question that should be closed, but can't be becuase of the bounty :-(

Comment: Why do you think it should be closed?

Comment: a) This site is about code, and occasionally tools, b) the question is a bit vague. What have you done so far to find this on your own? What sites didn't you like? Help us narrow down the search...

Comment: a) Well, it's also about the software industry - see the 'related' sidebar for a bunch of other industry questions. b) Okay, I've run Google searches for every combination of keywords I could think of, and there are lots of estimates both of the total size of the software industry and of breakdown by _company_. What seems to be surprisingly hard to obtain is a breakdown by _sector_. Is embedded bigger than enterprise IT? Has the web really become bigger than desktop software? Etc.

Comment: So a bounty is how we circumvent people's narrow definition of what should be on this site.  Good to know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something. China only, and the breakdown isn't very detailed, but it is relevant data: http://tmt.interfaxchina.com/news/2609

Answer (score 5):

Here is some [information](http://www.bsa.org/country/Public%20Policy/~/media/Files/Policy/Security/General/sw_factsfigures.ashx) on how each country does globally and the different sectors affected.

And some more details from [2008](http://www.infoedge.com/product_type.asp?product=DO-4959)

Comment: +1 - there's some good information there.  But industries is not the same as the sectors rwallace is after.  Also, the BSA is a trade lobbyist, and has pushed some dodgy numbers in the past, e.g., their estimates of edconomic harm caused by software piracy.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can find the information from the links on the wikipedia page about the ["software industry"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_industry). But for good information/statistics/reports, you probably have to pay for it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just looking for a rough overall estimate. But I wasn't able to find even that linked from the Wikipedia page, I don't suppose you could give any more specific pointers to what I'm missing?

Comment: here is a report from google answers about size of software industry, quite detailed but it is quite old, back to 2003, not sure if it helps. 
http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/237465.html